# neo4j syntax error on reduce

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm working with Neo4j 2.1.3 and trying to get shortest routes between two nodes. I use this cypher code:

```
start a=node(10118), b=node(10141)
match p=a-[r*2..5]->b
with p, relationships(p) as rcoll
return p, reduce(totalTime=0, x in rcoll: totalTime + x.time) as totalTime
order by totalTime
```

but I get "Neo.ClientError.Statement.InvalidSyntax" pointing on the word 'reduce'. any idea what's wrong?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace the : with a |

like this:

```
start a=node(10118), b=node(10141)
match p=a-[r*2..5]->b
with p, relationships(p) as rcoll
return p, reduce(totalTime=0, x in rcoll | totalTime + x.time) as totalTime
order by totalTime
```